# rollback/commit in spring using @transactional for 3 methods

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, commit, rollback

I am working on a spring project. We  use JPA and hibernate in  the project.I have 3 transactions in different methods which writes to db(2nd transaction needs id of first transaction and 1st transaction using save method) and I am calling these 3 methods  in a single method(in business logic).How can i rollback other 2 methods if any one of these fails.I searched a lot but the answer does not meet my requirements(I don't want to write transaction manager on my own).Can I use @transactional annotation here? what are the disadvantages of using @transactional annotation?I heard it causes db lock.If it causes DB lock, in what condition it will cause db lock?.Thanks in advance

Comment: Make the single method transactional.

Comment: what about the third method .. what is its contribution in the flow ?

Comment: in addition to @M.Deinum 's comment, make sure that neither of the three methods REQUIRES_NEW ... this assumes that you are using container managed transaction... if you are using application managed transaction & EM you will need to pass the EM to each of the callees

Comment: Thanks  @M.Deinum and @osama(third method just insert an entry in another table) for suggestions. I am using a single method tranactional. It is working.I just edited my question.Now my query is does this cause DB lock (or any other problem) in any conditions?